# Can I use a condition inside a toggleClass based on the toggle status

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, toggle

I am creating a toggle and need to execute a command based on the toggle status.

When I click `.flip1` first time it adds the `flipped` class to `.card1`. 
I also want it to show an alert "flipped added"

When I click it again it removes the `flipped` class and I want it to show an alert "flipped removed".

I imagine that the code will look something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.flip1').click(function () {

        $('.card1').toggleClass('flipped');

          if ("class added"){
            alert("flipped added");
          }
          if ("class removed"){
            alert("flipped removed");  
          }
        });
});
```

Is there something I can put in the `if` to know whether the toggle is true or false?

Comment: Can you share the relevant `HTML` please? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved via [jQuery's `hasClass()` method](https://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) like so:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.flip1').click(function() {

      $('.card1').toggleClass('flipped');

      // use hasClass to see if .card1 has .flipped class now applied.
      // if true, that indicates it was just added
      if ($('.card1').hasClass('flipped')) {
        alert("flipped added");
      } else {
        alert("flipped removed");
      }
    }
  );
});
```

```css
.flipped {
background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="card1">
Card1 (yellow if flipped)
</div>

<a href="#" class="flip1">
Flip1
</a>
```

Comment: That was fast and exactly what I was looking for, Thanks you

Comment: Great - glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `addClass()` and `.removeClass()` to change class and `.hasClass()` to check the state.

Here is your code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.flip1').on('click', function () {
            if ( $('.card1').hasClass('flipped') ) {
               $('.card1').removeClass('flipped');

               alert("flipped removed"); 

            } else {
               $('.card1').addClass('flipped');

               alert("flipped added");

             }

    });
```

});

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.flip1').on('click', function () {
        if ( $('.card1').hasClass('flipped') ) {
            $('.card1').removeClass('flipped');
            alert("flipped removed"); 
        } 
        else {
            $('.card1').addClass('flipped');
            alert("flipped added");
        }
    });
});
```